# Can my unwrapped UV be scaled outside of the UV grid?

Tags: uv

So I have UV unwrapped an object, and everything fits inside the UV grid as it should. But why should it remain within the UV grid?

Do I need to keep it within bounds or can I scale it outside the grid?

Comment: If you go outside of the grid/texture you will have the UV's copying the same texture as other parts, the texture tiles infinitely in all directions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you extend the UV grid the size of the texture will change inverse proportionally. If you make the UVs larger the texture will get smaller and start repeating itself.

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the gif! But is it ok for me to scale it up or is it a bad practice?

Comment: All depends on what you want

Comment: It is not bad practice. It can be used to "fake" increased texture resolution. In some instances it is very hard to spot the repetition.